# How Do I Put These String Variables into a Range?

Tags: excel, vba

The below code assigns number values to the two variables ColumnNumber1 and ColumnNumber2, then coverts them to letters.

```
Dim ColumnNumber1 as Long
Dim ColumnNumber2 as Long

Dim ColumnLetter1 As String
Dim ColumnLetter2 As String

ColumnNumber1 = 1
ColumnNumber2 = 2

ColumnLetter1 = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber1).Address, "$")(1)
ColumnLetter2 = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber2).Address, "$")(1)
```

Now, ColumnLetter1 = A and ColumnLetter2 = B. So far, so good. I want to put these into a range like this:

```
range("A:B")
```

but VBA rejects everything I try, such as

```
range("ColumnLetter1:ColumnLetter2")
```

What is the correct way to put ColumnLetter1 and ColumnLetter2 into the range format?

Comment: It is doing that because you're trying to pass a string that contains "ColumnLetter1:ColumnLetter2" to the range function. VBA doesn't know that you want it to fill in the contents of variables named ColumnLetter1 or ColumnLetter2 in those places. Use simoco's answer. It will do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
Range(ColumnLetter1 & ":" & ColumnLetter2)
```

another option is to use column *number*:

```
Range(Cells(1, ColumnNumber1), Cells(1, ColumnNumber2)).EntireColumn
```

both approaches gives you `Range("A:B")` for `ColumnNumber1 = 1` and `ColumnNumber2 = 2`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Sub marine()
    Dim ColumnNumber1 As Long
    Dim ColumnNumber2 As Long

    Dim ColumnLetter1 As String
    Dim ColumnLetter2 As String

    ColumnNumber1 = 1
    ColumnNumber2 = 2

    ColumnLetter1 = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber1).Address, "$")(1)
    ColumnLetter2 = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber2).Address, "$")(1)

    Set r = Range(ColumnLetter1 & ":" & ColumnLetter2)
End Sub
```